# InputStream skips bytes

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream

For the second time I have this extremely anoying problem with an InputStream.
This InputStream belongs to a Socket that is supposed to receive an image. The code for reading this image is as below:

```
InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();

InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(input);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
int total = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
int bytesRead = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[total]; // total is the total size of the image

while (bytesRead < total) {
    int next = input.read(buffer, bytesRead, total-bytesRead);
    if (next > 0) {
        bytesRead += next;
        System.out.println("Read: " + bytesRead);
    }
}
```

Now the strange thing is that this code skips the first 1182 bytes of the image, and then reads the remaining part. So when the `total` size is 15000 bytes, it reads byte 1182-15000.

I checked Wireshark and the whole image is transmitted. The code throws no exceptions. `input.read()` returns -1 as usual.

Pervious data has been readed from the stream using a `BufferedReader`. This data is only 5 characters long so it can't contain the missing 1K, but my guess is that the BufferedReader.readLine() method reads (buffers) more bytes from the InputStream than needed. Could this be correct?

I've had the same problem a few months ago but I absolutely have no clue on how I solved it.

Hope anyone can help.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I can solve the problem by adding a 100 ms sleep between sending the image size and the image data. It solves the problem but I would still realy like to know a more appropriate solution

Comment: It sounds very unlikely to me. It seems more likely that the stream doesn't *really* contain the data. By the way, you should note that if you reach the end of the stream unexpectedly, you'll loop forever... Have you tried looking at the network data via Wireshark? Are you doing *nothing* else with the stream?

Comment: Out of interest (similarly to the question above); how do you know it's the *first* 1182 bytes that are missing?

Comment: So this is like `DataInput.readFully()`

Comment: Jon -- if they reach the end of the stream, I think next will be set to -1 the first time, but then they'll get an EOFException, no? Though I agree, next being -1 should really be the end condition of the loop.

Comment: I ckecked the data read from the stream and compared it to the image file in a hex-editor. The FIRST aprox 1200 bytes are missing. This number changes sometimes. I also checked wireshark, the TCP data does contain the header of the image. So the whole image is transmitted. Before sending the image, the stream has already received some data. But this data is all read, so the stream is empty.

Comment: And no exceptions are thrown, input.read() just returns -1 as usual.

Comment: @thomaatje: If so, perhaps the cause of problem is in the code that reads these previous data. It somehow consumes beginning of the image.

Comment: @axtavt The previous code reads the image size using a BufferedReader. This data is terminated with a new line (/n) and always reads correctly. Even if I check the size of the previous String, it's not more than 5 so the missing 1K can't be in there. My guess is that the BufferedReader might read more bytes than needed when I call BufferedReader.readLine();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the name `**Buffererd**Reader` indicates it will snarf more bytes than just the first line from the underlying reader and hence also from the stream. Otherwise if would not be called "buffered".

Unfortunately I'm not aware of any non-deprecated class in Java which allows mixing of binary and textual data in the way you want.

I suggest, that you modify your protocol and transfer the length of the image also in some binary encoding. Then you can stick to `InputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the `BufferedReader` will assume that whatever reading operations you're performing afterwards will go through it, so it will happily consume input in increments of its buffer size.

One thing you could do is use a `BufferedInputStream` on top of `input`, instantiate a `DataInputStream` on top of that to do the `readLine()`, and then use the `BufferedInputStream` in your loop. The documentation says `readLine` is deprecated because it doesn't convert bytes to characters properly, but I'm hoping that with your first line containing only decimal digits, it shouldn't run into that problem.

I've written a short test, I hope it covers your use case:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

class test{

    static byte[] b;

    static {
        b = new byte[123456];
        java.util.Random r = new java.util.Random();
        for (int i=0;i<b.length;i++)
            b[i] = (byte)(r.nextInt());
    }

    static void client() throws Exception{

        Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 9000);

        InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();

        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(input);

        //read in length
        DataInputStream dais = new DataInputStream(bis);
        int total = Integer.parseInt(dais.readLine());
        System.out.println("Total: "+total);

        int bytesRead = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[total]; 

        while (bytesRead < total) {
            int next = bis.read(buffer, bytesRead, total-bytesRead);
            if (next > 0) {
                bytesRead += next;
                System.out.println("Read: " + bytesRead);
            }
        }

        for (int i=0;i<buffer.length;i++)
            if (buffer[i]!=b[i]){
                System.err.println("Error");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        System.out.println("OK");

        bis.close();
        socket.close();
    }

    static void server() throws Exception{
        ServerSocket srv = new ServerSocket(9000);

        Socket sock = srv.accept();

        OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
        BufferedOutputStream bos =new BufferedOutputStream(os);
        DataOutputStream daos = new DataOutputStream(bos);

        //we're sending the b buffer

        //send the length in plain text, followed by newline
        byte[]num = String.valueOf(b.length).getBytes();
        daos.write(num,0,num.length);
        daos.write(10);
        //send actual buffer contents
        bos.write(b, 0, b.length);
        os.close();

        srv.close();
        sock.close();    

    }

    public static void main(String[]args){

        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                try{server();}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                try{client();}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        }}).start();

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your awnser. I'll try this setup once I can get to my code again. It looks good!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just sending the image data (without the preceding image size) and using an external library such as [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) to handle this for you? In particular, I think that you will find [IOUtils.toByteArray(InputStream input)](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toByteArray%28java.io.InputStream%29) interesting, e.g.

```
InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
byte[] buffer = IOUtils.toByteArray(input);
```

Comment: I have been looking for something like this. But when using such library, how do I know when I received the whole image if the total size is unknown?